# excel adding incorrectly due to rounding

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Example of sheet]

On the attached worksheet you can see it is adding the column be incorrectly.  I believe it is due to the field b12 actually being 4.5 but the field rounds to 5 but when I have it subtract that field it sees it at 4.5 instead of the 5 that shows in the field.  I need it to read it as a 5.  How do I do that?

Comment: The total field formula is just =b11-b12

Comment: There is a difference in how a number is displayed and the actual number.  The number stored is 4.5 but because the cell format has been set to show only the integer it shows 5.  If you want the number to be 5 you will need to round the number either before or during the calculation: `=ROUND(B11,0)-ROUND(B12,0)`  You can see the `.5 ` by adding decimal places to the cell format.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it was easy but I couldn't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Excel *always* uses the complete value of any cell for calculations. The display formatting (which often implies rounding) are only applied for the human looking at it.
If you want a calculation done with the rounded value, you have to specify this explicitly in the formula, using `ROUND()` accordingly.

Comment: @Bradyt  do believe `Round()` allows you to round up or down, so before you go asking a second question, do your research.